# Como criar um evento, ao mouse atingir uma certa área da aplicação

Tags: delphi, eventos-do-mouse, delphi-xe5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em delphi xe5 e gostaria de fazer um menu abrir ao mouse "entrar" numa área do meu form.

É meio complicado explicar, mas vou tentar ...
A barra de tarefas do windows tem essa opção, ela fica oculta e quando você chega com o mouse aonde ela fica (geralmente embaixo) a barra aparece.

Gostaria de saber como posso implementar isso no delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer é tratar pelo evento onMouseMove

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
const
  HEIGHT_TITULO_JANELA = 50;
begin
  pnl1.Visible :=  (Y > (Height - pnl1.Height) - HEIGHT_TITULO_JANELA);

end;
```

se quiser controlar a exibição na lateral ao invés do Bottom, basta:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  pnl1.Visible :=  (X < pn1.Width); // para a esquerda
  pnl2.Visible :=  (X > (Width - pnl2.Width)); // para a direita
end;
```

Comment: Utilizando esta procedure, ao inicializar meu form, o panel já está visível, e ao perder o "foco" a ideia era de torná-lo oculto.

Comment: sete a propriedade visible dele para false em designTime ou no Create do Form

Comment: Já está setado para Visible false.

Comment: quando inicia ele está invisível, pq o vísible está false. Se você aproximar ele fica visível. Agora você quer que quando a janela perder o foco ele suma também? é isso?

Comment: Graças à sua ideia, consegui chegar à seguinte solução:

  if (PanelMenu.Visible=false) and (Mouse.CursorPos.X < PanelMenu.Width) then
    PanelMenu.Visible := true
  else
    PanelMenu.Visible := false;

Comment: o panel está na lateral? Então é só trocar mesmo. Você só não precisa do IF.  `PanelMenu.Visible := (Mouse.CursorPos.X < PanelMenu.Width)`

Comment: Exato, a ideia é fazer uma aplicação similar ao Design do Windows 8, com um menu lateral

Comment: Adicionei os exemplos para lateral.